# Prove that $\dot {\gamma_w} (0) = w.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, frechet-derivative

> Let $\Bbb E^n$ be the Euclidean $n$-space. Let $p \in \Bbb S^{n-1},$ the $(n-1)$-sphere in $\Bbb E^n.$ Let $w \in T_p \Bbb S^{n-1},$ the subspace of $\Bbb E^n$ parallel to the affine subspace tangent to $\Bbb S^{n-1}$ at $p.$ Consider the map $\gamma_w : (-1,1) \longrightarrow \Bbb E^n$ defined by $$\gamma_w (t) = \frac {p+wt} {\sqrt {\left \langle p +wt, p+ wt \right \rangle}},\ t \in (-1,1).$$ Prove that $\dot {\gamma_w} (0) = w.$

Consider the map $g : \Bbb E^n \longrightarrow \Bbb E^n$ defined by $g(v) = \frac {v} {\sqrt {\left \langle v, v \right \rangle}},\ v \in \Bbb E^n.$ and the map $f : (-1,1) \longrightarrow \Bbb E^n$ defined by $t \mapsto p+tw,\ t \in (-1,1).$ Then $\gamma_w = g \circ f.$ So by Chain rule we have $$\dot {\gamma_w} (0) = D\gamma_w (0) (1) = Dg(f(0)) (w) = Dg(p) (w).$$

How do I compute $Dg(p)\ $? Can anybody please help me in this regard?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You want a linear transformation $T(w)$ that satisfies $\frac{1}{\left\|h\right\|}\left\|\frac {w+h} {\sqrt {\left \langle (w+h), (w+h) \right \rangle}}-\frac {w} {\sqrt {\left \langle w, w \right \rangle}}-T(w)h\right\|\to 0$. Simplify this and make a guess.

Comment: I tried to see $g$ as a composition of three maps. $f_1 : t \mapsto tv, f_2 : t \mapsto \frac {1} {\sqrt t}$ and $f_3 : v \mapsto \left \langle v,v \right \rangle.$ Then $g = f_1 \circ f_2 \circ f_3\ $? Am I right @Matematleta?

Comment: Also $f_3$ can be further broken down to two another maps which are $f_4 : v \mapsto (v,v)$ and $f_5 : (v,v) \mapsto \left \langle v,v \right \rangle.$ Then $f_3 = f_5 \circ f_4.$ Here $f_4$ is linear and $f_5$ is bilinear. So $g = f_1 \circ f_2 \circ f_5 \circ f_4.$ Please check my reasoning @Matematleta.

Comment: Sorry I did some mistake here. The map $f_1$ is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential $Dg$ is just given by the Jacobian matrix. You can compute it in coordinates easily. If $v = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$, then

$$ g(v) = (g_1,\dots,g_n) = \left( \frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}}, \; \dots, \; \frac{x_n}{\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}} \right) $$

You can compute the partial derivates using the quotient rule. You get
$$ \frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_i} = \frac{|v|^2-x_i^2}{|v|^3} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j} = \frac{-x_ix_j}{|v|^3} $$
where $i \neq j$. Putting it all together, you get
$$ Dg(v) = \frac{1}{|v|^3}\begin{pmatrix} |v|^2-x_1^2 & -x_1x_2 & \cdots & -x_1x_n \\
-x_2x_1 & |v|^2-x_2^2 & \cdots & -x_2x_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
-x_nx_1 & -x_nx_2 & \cdots & |v|^2-x_n^2 \end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{|v|} \mathrm{Id}_n - \frac{1}{|v|^3} v \, v^\top $$
Here, $v$ is a column vector, and $v^\top$ is the transpose row vector, so $v \, v^\top$ is the matrix whose entries are $x_ix_j$.

When $p$ is on the unit sphere, $|v|=1$, and this simplifies to:
$$ Dg(p) = \mathrm{Id}_n - p \, p^\top $$

Now plug in $w$. The first term gives $\mathrm{Id}_n w = w$, and since $w$ is in the tangent plane to $p$, you have $p^\top w = 0$, so the second term vanishes.

Comment: This computation is quite clumpsy. I initially thought about it but gave up because of computation. Is there any smarter way available using chain rule?

Comment: Only if you can write $g$ as a composition, but I don't immediately see a way to do that in a nice way. There is probably some generic way to write a "product rule" when you have a function $g(v) = a(v)b(v)$, where $a(v)$ is a scalar function (in your example $\frac{1}{|v|}$) and $b(v)$ is a vector function (in your example $v$), but proving it would involve just a more complicated and generic version of the calculation in my answer above.

Comment: By the way, I think the "product rule" I mentioned above would be that the Jacobian of $g(v) = a(v)b(v)$ is given by $Dg(v) = \nabla a(v) \, b(v)^\top + a(v) \, Db(v)$. It is similarly simple by just using the product rule on each component separately.

Comment: Hmm. Good point. Thanks for your help. Do you have any idea about the problem https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3962456/512080

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with functional analysis.